# Unorthodox form structure in angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am trying to use angular-formly to construct my forms and the only one I can't figure out is the form that has a little strange structure. So the form structure is like so:

```
[checkbox]
[radio]
[text-input]

[checkbox]
[radio]
[text-input]

[checkbox]
[radio]
[text-input]
```

An example result HTML structure (very crude) would be this: http://jsbin.com/bebinivaba/edit?html,output

...

The problem is that the radio buttons need to be from the same radio group. And the only way I saw to do that is by specifying the options in a "options" object, in the templateOptions property. So there seems to be no way of inserting anything between the radio buttons...

I am using the [Bootstrap Template](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap) for the fields rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://kentcdodds.jsbin.com/pemalec/edit?html,js,output

Basically, you simply must specify a `name` on each field definition that is the same for all of them. In my example, I generate it like this:

```
var radioName = new Date().getTime() + 'radios';
```

Just to make sure it's unique, but you could use a `uuid` or something. I recommend generating it like this otherwise you could wind up with other radios having the same name that you don't want to have the same name :-)

Comment: The problem is that in my layout, the radio options are not next to each other, but have a text input and a checkbox in between... Something like this: http://jsbin.com/bebinivaba/edit?html,output

Comment: Now I understand! The example was not what I was looking for, but at the end I got it! Thank you so much!!!